# Plotting projected data in other projectons using cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cartopy

This question is in regards to plotting some data I have that uses the Lambert Conformal (LCC) CRS. While these questions specifically pertain to plotting LCC data in multiple projections, it also applies to the use of cartopy in general in that I would like to better understand the logic/process of plotting using cartopy.

Below are some code examples of what I am trying to do. The first example is simply plotting some LCC data. The data I used are available in the link [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Als9AH3QEmzgbQJ6CXn4URdMbCo).

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

proj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_latitude = 25, 
                             central_longitude = 265, 
                             standard_parallels = (25, 25))

# Data and coordinates (from download link above)
with np.load('nam_218_20120414_1200_006.npz') as nam:
   dat = nam['dpc']
   lat = nam['lat']
   lon = nam['lon']

ax = plt.axes(projection = proj)
ax.pcolormesh(lon, lat, dat, transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cf.NaturalEarthFeature(
               category='cultural',
               name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
               scale='50m',
               facecolor='none'))
ax.coastlines('50m')
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS)
plt.show()
```

The plot produced can be seen here:

**US Dewpoints on LCC Map**

[image]

My first confusion when using cartopy was why I always have to transform to `PlateCarree` when plotting? My initial thought was the `transform` keyword of the `pcolormesh` call needed the LCC projection information and not `PlateCarree`.

Next, if I want to plot my LCC data in another projection, e.g. Orthographic, would I go about doing so like below?

```
# First, transform from LCC to Orthographic
transform = proj.transform_points(ccrs.Orthographic(265,25), lon, lat)
x = transform[..., 0]
y = transform[..., 1]

ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.Orthographic(265,25))
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, dat, transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cf.NaturalEarthFeature(
               category='cultural',
               name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
               scale='50m',
               facecolor='none'))
ax.coastlines('50m')
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS)
ax.set_global()
```

The plot produced can be seen here:

**US Dewpoints on Orthographic Map**

[image]

I think the Orthographic map looks right, but I'd like to be sure that I understand the process of re-projection with cartopy correctly.

In summary, I would like to know the following things:

1. Do you always have to `transform` to `PlateCarree` when plotting? Why or why not?
2. Does re-projecting simply require a call to the `transform_points` method or are there other steps involved?

**Update 1**

Based on the answer from [@swatchai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2177413/swatchai), it seems as though the answer to my Question 2 is that `transform_points` is not required. One can simply use the `transform` keyword argument in many matplotlib plotting methods. This is what I thought originally. However, skipping the `transform_points` has not worked for me. See example below:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.Orthographic(265,25))
ax.pcolormesh(lon, lat, dat, transform = proj)
ax.add_feature(cf.NaturalEarthFeature(
               category='cultural',
               name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
               scale='50m',
               facecolor='none'))
ax.coastlines('50m')
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS)
ax.set_global()
```

Which produces this plot:

**Orthographic Plot Without transform_points Step**

[image]

The problem appears to be that the lat and lon input does not get transformed into the grid coordinates so they only get plotted in an extremely small area of the plot. So, to expand upon Question 2, if you are supposed to skip `transform_points` is there a bug in cartopy's plotting methods based on my above example? Or am I still missing a step?

Comment: Please post some of your data points. I suspect that you have (lat, long) data only.  Also,  some values of long is not in the range (-180, 180) degrees.

Comment: I have added a link to the data in the question. With regard to the range of longitudes, changing all value to be (-180, 180) does not change the plotting result when trying to convert LCC to Orthographic. It seems as though when I use the `PlateCarree` transform with grid coordinates x,y or raw lat,lon the plot works. It's just confusing because in the second case I do nothing to convert the coordinates as in the first case.

Comment: Your update 1 example is only correct if your data have corrdinates in an orthographic coordinate system (which they aren't). In general, `projection` tells cartopy what the drawn map should look like, and `transform` tells cartopy what coordinate system your data is represented in. You can set `projection` to any projection you like, but `transform` needs to match whatever coordinate system your data uses.

Comment: @ajdawson OK. That helps clarify. What confuses me is that it still sounds like the Update 1 example should work. `proj` is defined above as LCC (which is what the data are in) and is passed to `transform`. `projection` is given the Orthographic parameters (as this is how I want to re-project my LCC data). So, when I read your comment, it looks like I am doing what I am supposed to; though I still seem to be missing something.

Comment: My apologies, I misread, I see that you would expect this to work. Have you checked the units of your Lambert projection coordinates, cartopy is expecting them in metres, often they are supplied in km, which causes the plot to be too small.

Comment: @ajdawson The LCC coordinates come in as raw lat/lon. After creating my `proj` object I use `x_limits` and `y_limits` and that seems to indicate things are in meters (~10^7 m). If I use `proj` in the `transform` argument with `ax.set_global`, I get extents that are ~10^6 m. When I do not call `ax.set_global` I do see the plot and the extents are the same limits as the raw lat/lon data. What that tells me, and is what I mentioned in my comment on @swatchai answer, is that the data are not correctly converted to meters when simply passing my LCC `proj` to the `transform` argument.

Comment: @ajdawson I found [these plotting examples](http://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot.html) from a python package that uses cartopy to plot data from the WRF model. The process is nearly identical to mine. There they talk about having to use `transform_points` to get things to work. Is this just a case where cartopy does not have this transformation automated in the plotting function yet?

Comment: If your coordinates are lat/lon then the appropriate transform is `PlateCarree()`. If the coordinate values are with respect to the Lambert conformal coordinate system then you would need `LambertConformal(...)`. It sounds like `PlateCarree()` is what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An important distinction needs to be made between geographic and projected (or grid) coordinates. A more detailed description of those can be found [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/what-are-map-projections.htm). The important thing, and what helps to answer Question 1, is that latitude and longitude are *geographic* coordinates whereas points that have units in meters are *projected* coordinates.

The numerical weather model where the example data came from uses the Lambert Conformal projection in its calculations (more [here](http://computing.io/wp/2016/01/wrf-latitudes-ellipsoids-and-datums/)). However, the coordinates that get output are latitude and longitude. If you are inexperienced with spatial data, you can end up thinking that the lat/lon pairs are LCC *projected* coordinates when they are in fact *geogrphic* coordinates; the LCC stuff is used during model integration.

To answer Question 1, no, you do not always have to use `PlateCarree` as the source CRS. You do, however, always use `PlateCarree` for latitude and longitude data (which was the case here). This way cartopy will correctly transform your lat/lon values into *projected* coordinates (in meters) and be able to easily `transform` your data to other projections during plotting. This issue is ultimately the reason for the seemingly blank plot in Update 1. By saying the source data have LCC projected coordinates in `transform`, cartopy took the lat/lon input and interpreted them as having units of meters. The data did get plotted, but the extent was so small that it was impossible to see them without changing the plot extent to be the same as the data.

With regard to Question 2, no, using `transform_points` is not a requirement. cartopy was set up in such a way to make is easy to plot in multiple projections with minimal intermediary steps. As @swatchai mentioned, sometimes you may want to use the actual projected coordinates and using the `transform_points` method will allow you to do that. When `transform_points` was used to produce the second plot in the original post it essentially was manually doing what would have automatically been done had the input coordinates been handled properly with `PlateCarree` in `transform`.

Finally, an important clarification was made by @ajdawson with regard to how to use `projection` and `transform` when plotting. Once you understand what you have for source coordinates, this information is also useful. The comment is quoted below:

> In general, `projection` tells cartopy what the drawn map should look like, and `transform` tells cartopy what coordinate system your data is represented in. You can set `projection` to any projection you like, but `transform` needs to match whatever coordinate system your data uses.

Answer (score 5):

In Cartopy, ccrs.PlateCarree() is the most basic map projection, sometimes called un-projected projection, that is, a geo position (lat,long) in degrees -> becomes grid values y=lat; x=long on a PlateCarree map.

This snippet code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
axm = plt.axes( projection = ccrs.xxxx() )
```

creates an axis `axm` for plotting map in `xxxx` projection. When you plot data on axm, the default coordinates are grid (x,y) of that projection (usually in meters unit). That is why you need `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()` to declare that your input (x,y) are indeed in (long,lat) degrees, or in other words, in (x,y) of PlateCarree grid coordinates.

If your target projection is Orthographic while data is LambertConformal,

```
ax = plt.axes(projection = ccrs.Orthographic(265,25))
lccproj = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_latitude = 25, 
                         central_longitude = 265, 
                         standard_parallels = (25, 25))
```

You can plot the data with

```
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, dat, transform = lccproj)
```

No need to use transform_points() at all when you do the plotting. But it is useful when you want access to the transformed coordinates in some situation.

Comment: The `PlateCarree` comments were helpful. Using your example and skipping `transform_points` was how I thought cartopy was supposed to work. However, following your example and using `x = lon` and `y = lat` the data do not show. It seems the longitude and latitude do not get converted into the grid coordinates. The data are plotted but the coordinate mismatch leads to a very small overall extent of the data. Is it a cartopy bug? Not sure. I will update my question with an example of this since this gets at my original confusion with how cartopy works.