# Python - Temperature Interpolation

Tags: python, interpolation, temperature, cartopy, metpy

I am currently trying to use the code provided on this website (https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/gridding/Point_Interpolation.html#sphx-glr-examples-gridding-point-interpolation-py) to create a map of taiwan with the linear interpolation of data on a Jupyter notebook.

My data is in this form:

```
17070123, lat, lon, tem

C0A92, 25.27, 121.56, 29.3

C0AD0, 25.26, 121.49, 28.2

C0A94, 25.23, 121.64, 26.2

46691, 25.19, 121.52, 23.4

46690, 25.17, 121.44, 27.3

46693, 25.17, 121.54, 22.5

C0AD1, 25.15, 121.4, 28.5

46694, 25.13, 121.73, 28.6

C0A95, 25.13, 121.92, -999

C0A9B, 25.12, 121.51, 26.8

C0A9C, 25.12, 121.53, 28.3

C0A66, 25.11, 121.79, 27.8

C0A98, 25.11, 121.46, 29.6

C0A68, 25.09, 121.43, -999
```

and also in this form:

```
#17070123   lat lon T

C0A92   25.27   121.56  29.3

C0AD0   25.26   121.49  28.2

C0A94   25.23   121.64  26.2

46691   25.19   121.52  23.4

46690   25.17   121.44  27.3

46693   25.17   121.54  22.5

C0AD1   25.15   121.4   28.5

46694   25.13   121.73  28.6

C0A95   25.13   121.92  -999

C0A9B   25.12   121.51  26.8

C0A9C   25.12   121.53  28.3

C0A66   25.11   121.79  27.8

C0A98   25.11   121.46  29.6

C0A68   25.09   121.43  -999
```

My code looks like this:

```
# In[1]:

import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# In[2]:

from metpy.cbook import get_test_data
from metpy.gridding.gridding_functions import (interpolate, 
remove_nan_observations,
                                           remove_repeat_coordinates)


# In[3]:

def basic_map(map_proj):
   """Make our basic default map for plotting"""
   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
   view = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=to_proj)
   view.set_extent([120.5, 122.5, 24.5, 25.5])
   view.add_feature(cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural',

   name='admin_1_states_provinces_lakes',
                                                    scale='50m', 
facecolor='none'))
   view.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
   view.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
   view.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
   return view


# In[4]:

def station_test_data(variable_names, proj_from=None, proj_to=None):
    f = ('temp.txt')
    all_data = np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=0, delimiter='\t',
                      usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3),
                      dtype=np.dtype([('stid', '5S'), ('lat', 'f'), ('lon', 
                       'f'), ('T', 'f')]))
    all_stids = [s.decode('ascii') for s in all_data['stid']]
    data = np.concatenate([all_data[all_stids.index(site)].reshape(1, ) for 
site in all_stids])
    value = data[variable_names]
    lon = data['lon']
    lat = data['lat']
    if proj_from is not None and proj_to is not None:

        try:

            proj_points = proj_to.transform_points(proj_from, lon, lat)
            return proj_points[:, 0], proj_points[:, 1], value

        except Exception as e:

             print(e)
             return None

    return lon, lat, value


# In[5]:

from_proj = ccrs.Geodetic()
to_proj = ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_longitude=120.0000, 
central_latitude=25.0000)


# In[6]:

levels = list(range(20, 30, 1))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('magma')
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)


# In[7]:

x, y, temp = station_test_data('T', from_proj, to_proj)


# In[8]:

x, y, temp = remove_nan_observations(x, y, temp)
x, y, temp = remove_repeat_coordinates(x, y, temp)


# In[9]:

gx, gy, img = interpolate(x, y, temp, interp_type='linear', hres=75000)
img = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(img), img)
view = basic_map(to_proj)
mmb = view.pcolormesh(gx, gy, img, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(mmb, shrink=.4, pad=0, boundaries=levels)


# In[10]:

#Show map of TW with interpolated temps
plt.title("Interpolated Temperatures 17070100")
plt.show()
```

The code runs without an error, but I end up with an empty map of Taiwan.

I am super desperate, any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: I have no idea of this library, but it seems like you are representing the colormap outside the map itself. The code `view.set_extent([120.5, 122.5, 24.5, 25.5])` looks like you are setting the coordinates. However the center of the map `to_proj = ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_longitude=120.0000, 
central_latitude=25.0000)` is outside that box...

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add data to a cartopy map, it is important to remember to define the coordinate system. In this case, since your data is in lat/lon I'd start by doing something like:

```
view.pcolormesh(..., transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

You might also be interested in seeing the transform keyword being used in earnest at [Plotting projected data in other projectons using cartopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237802/plotting-projected-data-in-other-projectons-using-cartopy).